# Как вызвать JavaScript в скрипте Python?

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi

Есть плата (raspberry pi3), к цифровым входам которой прицеплена кнопка.

Скрипт зажигает диод, когда происходит нажатие на кнопку (диод горит быстрее). Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии кнопки вызывался JavaScript, который за собой тянет еще `web3.js` и записывает в бд, к которой подключается, нынешнее время, таким образом фиксируется время нажатия кнопки.

Прочитала про `Js2py`, утилита, позволяющая заставить python понимать javascript, но так и не могу понять, как заставить вызываться скрипт каждый раз, когда активна кнопка.
Скрипт кнопки такой:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Установим номера пинов GPIO, с которыми будем работать
LED = 4
KEY = 17

# Делаем сброс состояний портов (все конфигурируются на вход - INPUT)
GPIO.cleanup()
# Режим нумерации пинов - по названию (не по порядковому номеру на разъеме)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# Сконфигурируем пин LED на вывод (OUTPUT)
GPIO.setup(LED, GPIO.OUT)
# Установим низкий уровень (0) на пине LED
GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
# Сконфигурируем пин KEY на ввод (INPUT)
GPIO.setup(KEY, GPIO.IN)
# Выведем на экран текст-приветствие
print 'Hello! Blink...blink...'

# Проверка на прерывание программы с клавиатуры (CTRL+C)
try:
    # Вечный цикл
    while True:
        # Если кнопка нажата (на пине KEY низкий уровень 0V)
        if GPIO.input(KEY) == False:
            # Устанавливаем задержку 0,1 сек. и выводим сообщение
            timeout = 0.1
            print 'Key pressed.'

        else:
            # в противном случае задержка - 0,5 сек.
            timeout = 0.5
        # Засветим светодиод, подключенный к пину LED
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.HIGH)
        # Подождем (выполним заданную выше задержку)
        time.sleep(timeout)
        # Погасим светодиод, подключенный к пину LED
        GPIO.output(LED, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(timeout)
# Если комбинация клавиш CTRL+C была нажата - сброс пинов и завершение
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

`print 'Key pressed.'` - По идее, следом должен быть вызов скрипта, который фиксирует время, но как на него сослаться?

Новичок и очень надеюсь на помощь!

Comment: А зачем тут js? Не вижу смысла в одном скриптовом языке вызывать другой

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тут JavaScript? 
На Python очень просто можно подключиться к любой базе данных и сохранить туда время нажатия кнопки.